# Loading Properties file into Components in Mule

Tags: spring, mule, esb

I have a property file and I want to transform it to a java object that will be used in java components across all flows. What is the best approach for this in Mule CE 3.4

Comment: You have a .properties file which includes properties like `baseURL=localhost` and you need to inject some properties into spring beans? am i right?

Comment: yes, exactly. And use it in different components across different flows

Comment: Inject `${baseUrl}` in your bean.

Answer (score 3):

Add property resolver to your configuration. It is mostly done in applicationContext.xml. I am not sure if it is same in your configuration.

```
 <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:yourfile.properties" />
```

Then, your properties can be resolved in your beans with the help of `@Value` annnotation.

```
@Value("${PropertyName}")
private String propertyValue,

//Setter getter
```